# Create table in Excel with unique random letters

Tags: excel

I am currently trying to create a 10x31 table in Excel, where each cell has two letters in it (e.g., AB), and each row has a unique set of letters.

So that means that in one row not a single letter repeats, including paired letters. For example, FA and FG cannot be in the same row, because the letter F is repeated. How can I do it?

Comment: How do you plan to get 31 unique letters from an alphabet that contains 26 letters?

Comment: If you cannot repeat letters, then you can't type 31 unique letters because alphabet got less. You say FA and FG in the same row of 31 columns would not be valid because the F repeats. Unless FA and GF is valid (F is not in the same position), you won't be able to do it.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - you would still need 31 unique letters in the first position.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I mean that each row is 10 units long, and not a single letter can be repeated within a row, they can be repeated down a column, just not across a row

Answer (score 0):

Excel is extremely poorly suited to this, but here is what you can do.  Create a reference table that is 26x32.  The first row is the letters of the alphabet.  The rest of the table (31 cells below each letter) is all `RAND()`.

Create a second table that is 20x31. The formula in cell A1 should be `=INDEX(POSITIONS!$A$1:$Z$1,MATCH(LARGE(POSITIONS!$A2:$Z2,COLUMN()),POSITIONS!$A2:$Z2,0))`.

Where `POSITIONS!$A$1:$Z$1` are the letters and `POSITIONS!$A2:$Z2` are the first row of random numbers.  Copy this formula down and across, so every cell has a letter in it.  None of the letters should repeat across the row.

Finally, create your 10x31 table.  Creating the first row is a bit of a chore, since you must type `CONCAT(LETTERS!A1, LETTERS!B1)`, then manually increment it (since just copying right would create overlapping pairs).  After you finish that, you can copy down.

Comment: That helped a bit, but what I was really looking for was to have each row be different. In your example, each row is exactly the same, but I want each row to be different. There can be a few repeats between rows, just not have all the rows be the exact same.

Comment: Each row *should* be different.  Notice that `POSITIONS!$A2:$Z2` only anchors the columns, not the rows, so that as you copy down it should also refer to different rows of randomly generated numbers.  `POSITIONS` is really just 31 sets of randomly ordered letters, and each set should inform one row of your output.